# regular expression, multiline

Tags: regex, scripting, sed

I want to delete all the text between a pair of "};" which contains a particular keyword.
What i want is

input:

```
}; text text KEYWORD text text };
```

Output:

```
};   };
```

Suggest me a simple regular expression. I know 'sed' is to be used.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/please

Comment: sorry, i was not aware of protocols. i ll keep that in mind now onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work under most conditions:

```
sed '/};[^}]*};/{s/};[^}]*};/}; };/;b};/};/!b;:a;N;/\n[^}]*};/!ba;s/[^;]*\n.*\n[^}]*/ /' inputfile
```

There will probably be some corner cases where this fails. Change the space near the end to `\n` if you want the result to be on two lines.

Examples:

`}; test ;}` becomes `}; };`

`};

test

};` becomes `}; };`

`abc };

test

}; def` becomes `abc }; }; def`

`abc }; 111

test1

test2

222 }; def` becomes `abc }; }; def`

Answer (score 2):

```
\};[^}]*KEYWORD[^}]*\};
```

will work if there are no `}` between the two delimiters.

So:

```
sed 's/\};[^}]*KEYWORD[^}]*\};/}; };/g' file.in > file.out
```

Comment: but this would match the start and end markers as well right?

Comment: Yes, and they are replaced right back. sed doesn't have lookaround (GNU BRE engine).

Comment: Just match the whole thing and then replace it with the literal "}; };"

Comment: Hm. Does `sed 's/\};[^\}]*KEYWORD[^\}]*\};/}; };/g' file.in > file.out` work?

Comment: nop! same error! also there can be multiple lines between a pair of };. I tried using: `sed "s/[}][;][^}]*KEYWORD[^}]*[}][;]/}; };/g" file.in > file.out` . not working

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will match the thing that you want to delete -

```
(?<=\};).*?KEYWORD.*?(?=\};)
```

Edit: this wont work with sed as pointed out by @Tim as sed does not support lookarounds.

Comment: This is not looking for the keyword, and won't work in sed (no lookaround).

Comment: Thanks @Tim for bringing it to my notice. Fixed. And yeah this is general regex, I am not sure about any specifics with sed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach possible:

```
cat file.in | sed "/KEYWORD/s/};[^}]*};/}; };/g" > file.out
```